# Uncaught Reference Error: google is not defined google charts

Tags: javascript, android, google-visualization

I am trying to load Google charts in android application. But, it throws me error that google is not defined. Below is my HTML file and JavaScript file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Patient Vitals</title>

<link href="../../common/scripts/lib/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../common/scripts/lib/css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../common/scripts/lib/css/jquery.mobile.datebox.css" />
<link href="../scripts/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="../../common/scripts/jsapi.js" type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
<script src="../scripts/patient_vitals.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="PT_Care_vitals_swa_ofcurv_left"  onclick="getPatientVitalInfo();"</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

**patient_vitals.js:**

```
getPatientVitalInfo =function()
{
   logInformation("Get Patient Vital Information ");
   alert("Get Patient Vital info");
   //code to retieve data from database
   drawChart(temp); 
}

drawChart = function(temp) 
{
   alert("Inside drawChart function");
   //Convert array int DataTable
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(temp);
   rowCount = data.getNumberOfRows();
   // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
   chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   var options = {'tooltip': {'trigger':'none'}, 'year': "numeric", 'month':      "numeric",'day': "numeric", 'pointSize':5};
   //Function to perform select operation

   //Drawing the chart in HTML page
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Here, google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(temp) throws this error. Any idea about this? how to resolve it? I also tried to keep google.Visulization inside .js file. But it also not working. If I am running the same code from Browser, it is working fine. Is it problem with android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems a bit strange. Try change

```
<script src="../../common/scripts/jsapi.js" type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});</script>
```

Then the google object should be loaded correct. Also, you have pasted chart initialization from a google chart-example,

```
chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

but your only HTML is

```
<div class="PT_Care_vitals_swa_ofcurv_left"  onclick="getPatientVitalInfo();"</div>
```

you miss the `chart_div` id