# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined ( Google Chart )

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I tried to use Google Chart. The below line is giving me an error in the console:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["corechart"] });
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Here is my whole JS file

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery','google-pie-chart'], function($) {

  $(function() {

    var section_num = $('#as-section-num');
    var problem_set = $('#as-problem-set');
    var start_time = $('#as-start-time');
    var student_am = $('#as-student-am');
    var due_time = $('#as-due-time');
    var submit = $('#as-submit');
    var avg_score = $('#as-avgscore');

    var danger = $('#pc-danger');
    var warning = $('#pc-warning');
    var success = $('#pc-success');


    var basePath = "/BIM/resources/js/reports/section-exercise/";


    $.ajax({

      url: basePath + "data-r.json",
      type: "GET",
      dataType : "json",

      success: function( data ) {


        function updateInfo(x) {

          section_num.html(data[x].section_num);
          problem_set.html(data[x].problem_set);
          start_time.html(data[x].start_time);
          student_am.html(data[x].student_am);
          due_time.html(data[x].due_time);
          submit.html(data[x].submit);
          avg_score.html(data[x].avg_score);
          danger.html(data[x].danger);
          warning.html(data[x].warning);
          success.html(data[x].success);

        }

         // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
         google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

         function drawChart() {

           var options = {
            width: 160,
            height: 160,
            chartArea: {
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%"
            },


            colors: ['#F46E4E',  '#F9C262' , '#ADB55E',],
            legend: 'none',
            enableInteractivity: false,
            pieSliceText: 'none',

          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

          var x = {};

          for (var object in data) {

            console.log(object);

            var total = data[object].danger + data[object].warning + data[object].success ;

            x['data_'+object] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

              ['Piechart' , 'Number of Skills'],
              ['danger'   , ( data[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
              ['warning'  , ( data[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
              ['success'  , ( data[object].success/total ) * 100  ],

              ]);

          }

          chart.draw( x.data_A , options);

          $('#group-a').click(function() {
            updateInfo("A");  chart.draw( x.data_A , options);
          });
          $('#group-b').click(function() {
            updateInfo("B");  chart.draw( x.data_B , options);
          });
          $('#group-c').click(function() {
            updateInfo("C");  chart.draw( x.data_C , options);
          });
          $('#group-d').click(function() {
            updateInfo("D");  chart.draw( x.data_D , options);
          });

        }

      },

      error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );

        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
      },


    });

});

});
```

What did I do wrong ? Any hints / suggestions ?

Do I need to include something somewhere ?

Please kindly advise.

Comment: For `google` to be defined, you need to define it. To do so, just include Google Chart's JS in your HTML `<head>` tag: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it ? I'm pretty noob to all of these. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Just include that script tag in your head.. BEFORE including your script ;). In a nutshell, if you're used to any other kind of language, you are basically missing your #include.

Comment: Let me try that now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533789/uncaught-reference-error-google-is-not-defined-google-charts